# netflow v5 config not working - Juniper VMX

Tags: juniper, netflow

I use GNS3 and juniper vmx to practice netflow config. 
I know that v9 needs MPC card, so i use v5.
But no netflow export from my router.
`show services accounting flow` comes nothing
Do I miss any config?

```
root> show configuration |display set
set system processes dhcp-service traceoptions file dhcp_logfile
set system processes dhcp-service traceoptions file size 10m
set system processes dhcp-service traceoptions level all
set system processes dhcp-service traceoptions flag packet
set system ntp server 192.168.10.11
set interfaces ge-0/0/7 unit 0 family inet sampling input
set interfaces ge-0/0/7 unit 0 family inet address 172.18.0.1/24
set interfaces ge-0/0/8 unit 0 family inet address 192.168.10.51/24
set interfaces ge-0/0/9 unit 0 family inet sampling input
set interfaces ge-0/0/9 unit 0 family inet address 172.17.0.1/24
set interfaces fxp0 unit 0 family inet6 dhcpv6-client client-type stateful
set interfaces fxp0 unit 0 family inet6 dhcpv6-client client-ia-type ia-na
set interfaces fxp0 unit 0 family inet6 dhcpv6-client client-identifier duid-type duid-ll
set forwarding-options sampling input rate 1
set forwarding-options sampling family inet output flow-server 192.168.10.166 port 9996
set forwarding-options sampling family inet output flow-server 192.168.10.166 source-address 192.168.10.51
set forwarding-options sampling family inet output flow-server 192.168.10.166 version 5
set protocols router-advertisement interface fxp0.0
```

```
root> show chassis fpc 0
                     Temp  CPU Utilization (%)   CPU Utilization (%)  Memory    Utilization (%)
Slot State            (C)  Total  Interrupt      1min   5min   15min  DRAM (MB) Heap     Buffer
  0  Online           Testing  43         0       39     39     41    511        31          0

root> show services accounting flow

root>
```